# Excel VBA, Custom Class: Function call raises "method not supported" error

Tags: class, excel, vba

I am writing my first classes.
One is cCRElist which is essentially a collection of cCRE instances (some specialized events).

I want there to be a sub or function inside cCRElist that will load all the CRE's from the worksheet into one big collection I can work with. I created the function and it worked OK when I called it from a normal code module, but then I tried to move the code into the class. Now I am having trouble calling the function LoadFromWorksheet(myWS as Worksheet).

The error is "object does not support this property or method".  I have tried making it a sub, a function, making it public, not public, I have tried turning into a Property Let instead of a sub. Obviously I have a flimsy grasp on what that does.  I have tried

```
Call CREList.LoadFromWorksheet(myWS)
```

and

```
CREList.LoadfromWorksheet myWS
```

Same error every time.

Here is the test code that uses the class and calls the function:

```
Sub TestClassObj()
    Dim CRElist As cCRElist
    Set CRElist = New cCRElist

    Dim myWS As Worksheet

    Set myWS = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

    CRElist.LoadFromWorksheet (myWS)

End Sub
```

Here is a snippet of the class cCRElist:

```
' **** CLASS cCRElist
Option Explicit

' This is a collection of CRE objects
Private pCRElist As Collection

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set pCRElist = New Collection
End Sub

Public Property Get CREs() As Collection
    Set CREs = pCRElist
End Property

Public Property Set Add_CRE(aCRE As cCRE)
        pCRElist.Add aCRE
End Property

Function LoadFromWorksheet(myWS As Worksheet)
    Dim CRE As cCRE
    Dim iFirst As Long
    Dim iLast As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Set CRE = New cCRE

    iFirst = gHeader_Row + 1
    iLast = FindNewRow(myWS) - 1

    ' update data in CRE then add
    For i = iFirst To iLast
        If myWS.Cells(i, gCRE_Col) <> "" Then   ' This is a CRE row
            Set CRE = New cCRE
            With CRE
                .CRE_ID = myWS.Cells(i, gCRE_Col)
                If Not IsDate(myWS.Cells(i, gCRE_ETA_Col)) Then
                    .ETA = "1/1/1900"
                Else
                    .ETA = Trim(myWS.Cells(i, gCRE_ETA_Col))
                End If
                <... snipped ...>
            End With
            pCRElist.Add_CRE CRE
        End If
    Next
End Sub
' **** END OF CLASS cCRElist
```

Thanks for your expertise.

Comment: please confirm that you kept `Sub TestClassObj()` in standard module... in which line you get the error you mentioned? try with changing `Function LoadFromWorksheet(...)` back into `Sub LoadFromWorksheet(...)`. Try to get rid of parenthesis for parameter when you call this method.

Comment: in the vbe click tools-options, select the general tab and change the error trapping to 'break in class module' and then try the code again; this may help narrow down the true error

Comment: KazJaw...Yes, TestClassObj is in a standard module.  I get the error on the "CRElist.LoadFromWorksheet(myWS)" line.

Comment: Here is what worked. First, I did the "break in class module". In the test code, I made the calling line like this (which I had tried before):   `code`CRElist.LoadFromWorksheet myWS `code`.  Inside the class, i had to change what was actually `code` Set pCRElist.Add_CRE CRE `code` to `code` pCRElist.Add CRE `code`  Now it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what worked based on help I got in the comments. First, I did the "break in class module". In the test code, I changed the function call from:

```
CRElist.LoadFromWorksheet(myWS)
```

to

```
CRElist.LoadFromWorksheet myWS
```

Inside the class, i had to change

```
Set pCRElist.Add_CRE CRE
```

to

```
pCRElist.Add CRE
```

Then I was able to get rid of extraneous CLASS functions Add_CRE and Count.

Thanks for everyone's input. I couldn't figure out how to mark comments as accepted answers so I did this. Let me know if I need to do something differently.
Now it works!